# Adding items to TextBox AutoCompleteSource from database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My textbox uses AutoComplete, I get the items from the database, however I have around 1000+ items and it's making the form load slowly because I loop through the data I selected and add it to the `AutoCompleteSource` 1 by 1.

```
sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Column1 from Table", con)
sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
While sqldr.Read
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(sqldr("Column1").ToString())
End While
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Try like this : -http://hastebin.com/jogupugixo.vbs

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Worked! Thanks, put it as an answer so I can accept it, if you want.

Comment: I have posted as answer !!

Comment: Do you want to know **faster** or **another** or **working** or something else way?

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Your answer is **working** properly why should I post a new answer? :)

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ I think continuing the dialog makes no benefit. If something else way annoys you, I can post a new comment but you should know that comment is really a question from the OP to let other users know what exactly he wants :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load data to a `DataTable`

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT columnname FROM table", conn)
Dim ds As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
da.Fill(dt)
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    col.Add(dt.Rows(i)("columnname").ToString())
Next
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```